# MacOS: su pkill -9 “process_name” = sorry

Tags: osx, su, ownership, pkill

How to use `pkill` as `su` on a Mac?

When I run `su pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd"` in the terminal I get `su: Sorry` (but works as sudo). I am looking for a way to kill this process from inside a script that runs as `su`.

#### My application

I use SleepWatcher in MacOS to open Screen Sharing apps on wake up. After launching Screen Sharing app I want to kill the process `RFBEventHelperd` as this gives back <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Mac instead of being bound to OS running in Screen Sharing.

SleepWatcher runs wake script as `su`:

```
$ su - $user -c "$home/.wakeup"
```

#### Question

How can I put the `pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd"` into my script, and have it kill a process that's running as another user.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this a bit? It's confusing what you want to do here. You want to run `su - $user -c "pkill -9 RFBEventHelperd'` inside of another script that you already `su -c ..` in when you ran it?

Comment: I wouldn't use `su` inside the script that is already executed as `su`. I am testing it in the terminal. To make it clear, first 2 lines of my question talks about using pkill in the terminal as `su` followed by explanation of my application.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to make heads/tails of your question. It's still confusing to me. Perhaps you could add the contents of `ps -eaf` to show the process you're trying to kill? Sorry I'm trying to understand it but this lacks enough detail to help.

Comment: `su pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd"` results in `su: Sorry`, do you know how to use `pkill` as `su`?

Comment: I do, but you do too, you're showing `su - $user -c "<cmd>"`.

Comment: You keep saying "as `su`" what are you referring to here? Another user called `su`?

Comment: I ran this: `su - josh -c "pkill -9 RFBEventHelperd"` and got this `pkill: signalling pid 74510: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Right, so the user josh doesn't own that PID, what user does?

Comment: `pgrep -fl RFBEventHelperd`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80260/discussion-between-jsp-and-slm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of `su` that you're looking for is as follows:

```
$ su -c pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd" <user>
```

On OSX this form may not work. In those situations you'll likely have to yield to using `sudo` instead:

```
$ sudo -u <user> <cmd>
```

For this to run passwordless you'll have to create an entry for this in your `/etc/sudoers` file and utilize the NOPASSWD feature for an explicit command that your use running the original script has access to execute without being challenged for the password.

#### Using sudo

To set up a rule in `/etc/sudoers` file to allow this user access to do the `pkill` command one could add this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And with this the shell script can then run this command without any password:

```
$ sudo -u root /usr/bin/pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd"
```

**NOTE:** When dealing with `/etc/sudoers` edits you can use `visudo` like so:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

#### References

- [Enable sudo without a password on MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257813/enable-sudo-without-a-password-on-macos)

Comment: Thanks @slm. I added `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to `/etc/sudoers` file and added `sudo -u root /usr/bin/pkill -9 "RFBEventHelperd"` to the script and it is working fine. Is there any security drawback to this approach?

Comment: @Jsp - I added this to the answer. This seems like an appropriate way to address this. You've wisely narrowed the command to just 1 thing that a user in the `%admin` group can run, nothing bad that I can see with this.